# XMLHttpRequest gives CORS error where as $.ajax works

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

The jquery ajax code works absolutely fine

```
  $.ajax({
  url: rumi_api_endpoint + rumi_params + "filter/show",
  data: {"name":"ronak","country":"india"}, //return  data
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  async: true,
  success: function (res) {
    onComplete(res);
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log('Save error.');
  }
});
```

But native javascript XMLHttpRequest throws a CORS error.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    onComplete(res);
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST",rumi_api_endpoint + rumi_params + "filter/show",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json; charset=UTF-8");
var xyz = {
  "config": {"name":"ronak","country":"india"},
  "token": "abc"
}
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(xyz));
```

When i set the Content-Type as x-www-form-urlencoded, it is able to send the request as a stringified JSON.
When i don't set any header, it returns a 406 Not Acceptable error.
But when i want to send JSON, it gives CORS error.
Is there anything what i am missing using the native javascript approach?

Comment: The jQuery example is sending its data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` where as in the second example you're attempting to send the data as `application/json`. That's the difference.

Comment: I tried sending as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but the request is getting sent as string. When i remove JSON.stringify, the server gets [object object] as the request.

Comment: Remove the line that's setting the "Content-Type" header, and change the last line to: `xmlhttp.send($.param(xyz));`. The string that gets sent should look like this: `config[name]=ronak&config[country]=india&token=abc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the jQuery ajax request you are sending is considered "simple" and therefore follows the SOP less strictly (it doesn't send an OPTIONS request.) The native javascript ajax request you are sending is not considered "simple" because you added the Content-Type header.

To fix this, you'll of course need to remove the content-type header, and then since you are no longer setting the content-type header to `application/json`, you'll have to format your data to be a valid paramstring. With jquery it's as simple as `$.param(xyz)`, however, I'm assuming you're trying to do this without jQuery, so you'll need your data formatted as

```
config%5Bname%5D=ronak&config%5Bcountry%5D=india&token=abc
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS error happens when javascript tries to access an address outside its domain. I'm not familiar with jQuery to know why it is able to get thru compared to native ajax. Anyway, you can simply allow CORS in the http server config of the domain you are accessing (if that's possible).

Simply add this in the apache2.conf or httpd.conf in case of apache

```
<Directory /var/www>
#AllowOverride All
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "true"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
</Directory>
```

You can also create a `.htaccess` file to do that, in this case uncomment the `AllowOverride All` above and comment the rest.

hope this helps!

Comment: Currently, we are trying to build a framework. So when distributing, the server end changes are not in our hand. I am very curios to know how jquery is able to get thru the CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

We have our server in ruby. So we added the default format in our ruby code

```
default_format: json
```

The final JS code is

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    onComplete(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response));
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST",rumi_api_endpoint + rumi_params + "filter/show",true);
var xyz = {
  "config": {"name":"ronak","country":"india"},
  "token": "abc"
}
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(xyz));
```